# How to apply particle swarm optimization to a Neural network model in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I created a NN model with customised loss function.I would like to apply  PSO algorithm as my loss function, but how to apply PSO to NN

Answer (score -1):

You can use PySwarms is an extensible research toolkit for particle swarm optimization (PSO) in Python https://github.com/ljvmiranda921/pyswarms